# Unable to use populate method in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was try to fetch user details and profile at the same time but I found that I need to save profile id in user collection which weird to me because some of tutorials didnt state need to save profile id to user collection, so below is my code sample

**UserModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// const { Schema } = mongoose;
const { userStatus, userType } = require('../Config/setting')

const UserModel = mongoose.Schema({

    // Other fields
    profile: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Profile" // Refers to the Profile model
    },
 },   
 {
     timestamps: true,
     optimisticConcurrency: true,
     toJSON: { virtuals: true },
     toObject: { virtuals: true }
  })

 // UserModel.virtual('profile', {
 //     ref: 'Profile',
 //     localField: '_id',
//     foreignField: 'user',
//     // justOne: false
// });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserModel)
```

**Profile Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { userStatus } = require('../Config/setting')

const ProfileModel = mongoose.Schema({
    // Other fields
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User" // Refers to the User model
    },
}, {
   timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Profile", ProfileModel)
```

**Code Usage**

```
 const profile = asyncHandler(async (req, res)=> {

   const { email, username, id } = req.user

   const user_details = await User.findOne({ _id: id, username, email }).populate('profile');
   console.log(user_details.profile)
   if(!user_details){
       res.status(404)
       throw new Error("user_not_found");
   }

   return res.json({ status: true, data: user_details, message: 'success', code: 200 })
})
```

Current virtual populate method is working, but without saving profile id to user collection will not working at all. So is there any solution to show profile without saving id to the user collection?
I'm using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mendes.develop/joining-tables-in-mongodb-with-mongoose-489d72c84b60) as reference

Comment: Populate takes each `ObjectId` in your `User.profile` as a reference and peforms a lookup against the `profiles` collection to find each `Profile` document and replaces the `ObjectId` with the full document at execution time. How would mongoose do a populate to find each `Profile` for each `User` if you don't have that `ObjectId` stored? There is no way to do a populate without having a reference. It doesn't have to be the `ObjectId` it could be a number or string or anything that you can use to uniquely identify.

Comment: @jQueeny thanks for the reply but from the tutorial didnt show need to add profile id to user so I need to add profile id to the user?

Comment: Yes, in your case you would need to add the the profile `_id` value into the `User.profile` field. The tutorial you link is very basic and not particularly helpful but the author does add `user: user._id` so that is how he added the ref.